# Set width of div to be that of enclosed table

Tags: css

I have a table where one of the cells is like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="inner-table">
        <!--content-->
        </table>
    <div>
</td>
```

The div is there so I can put a border around the table, with a gap of 10px. As it displays, though, the div is the entire width of the enclosing td. What I would like is for it to be just the width of the table it wraps (plus margin, to be specified). I can't figure out the CSS to do this, simple though it no doubt is, although I've got it working with Javascript - but I would prefer to do it using CSS, if possible. I had hoped setting `width:auto` for the div would work, but it makes no difference,

Comment: Someting like this you need https://jsfiddle.net/a8oc9fku/

Comment: No, it still takes the width of the parent td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use inline-block

```
<style>
    .table-wrapper {
        border : 1px solid black;
        padding : 10px;
        display : inline-block; 
    }
</style>

<table width="400px">
<tr>
<td>
OUTER
</td>
<td>
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="inner-table">
        <tr><td>INNER</td></tr>
        </table>
    <div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I always forget inline-block! That was it.